# Positive function with zero lower integral

Tags: real-analysis

Give an example of a positive function $f(x):[0,1]\to(0,1]$ the lower integral of which is equal to zero.

Comment: ...please? You shouldn't demand things, it makes people less likely to be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: 
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if}~ x~\text{is irrational}\\
 1/n & \text{if}~x=m/n,~\text{where}~m,n\in \mathbb N,n\gt 0,\gcd(m,n) =1
\end{cases} $$